# Taranis x 7 will not turn on

Tags: transmitter

Hey guys I'm having a issues with my transmitter when i press the power there is a click from speaker and nothing happens after. I tried also press the bottom two left and power at the same time, same story. I reached out to frsky they said i have the incorrect fireware. So im trying to write a new firmware and this want pops up when procces with the writing. Please help any one.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking about the firmware. Could you edit to clarify precisely what you need help with in writing new firmware?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, that happened to my Taranis x9 Lite one time (just the sound click but then nothing turns on). I removed the batteries, and then opened the transmitter cover (or back cover) and removed and reinserted the cell coin battery, and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the cell coin battery, clean it with a cloth, and then put it in.

PS: I wanted to post this as a comment to the other answer, but for that I would have needed at least 50 reputation.